# Receiving alerts/commands from Azure IoT Hub to device

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

I am currently doing R & D on Azure IoT hubs using Windows10 IoT core and Raspberry PI 2. I am following the sample for reference [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/iot-hub-c-mbed-temperature-anomaly/) to send alerts to the device from IoT hub when the temperature of a room greater than 25 for example. But the sample is for mbed board.

To do this I developed a sample UWP app for Raspberry Pi which will send temperature data to IoT hub. In Azure I created a stream analytics job which will take IoT hub as input and filter the data( only temperature greater than 25 degrees) then send it to output EventHub. Here I created a worker role/cloud service which will read data from EventHub and send back to IoT hub to the same one which I am using for sending temperature information from raspberry pi.

Here my doubt is how can IoT Hub differentiate the data sent from raspberry pi and the data sent by worker role? and how can I receive only the data sent by worker role?

Because if I read cloud to device messages I am receiving the data which I sent from raspberry pi.

Here I got stuck, I tried the below code to read data from IoT Hub but getting all my messages sent from raspberry pi instead worker role messages that is only temperature greater than 25 messages.

```
public async void ReceiveDataFromCloud()
    {


        startingDateTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
        builder.TransportType = ppatierno.AzureSBLite.Messaging.TransportType.Amqp;

        factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);

        client = factory.CreateEventHubClient(eventHubEntity);
        group = client.GetDefaultConsumerGroup();
        receiver = group.CreateReceiver(partitionId.ToString(), startingDateTimeUtc);//startingDateTimeUtc
        for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                EventData data = receiver.Receive();

                if (data != null)
                {
                    var receiveddata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.GetBytes());

                    //var messageString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConferenceRooms>(receiveddata);                    

                    Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", data.SequenceNumber, data.EnqueuedTimeUtc.ToLocalTime(), Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.GetBytes()));

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

                await Task.Delay(2000);

            }

        }

        receiver.Close();
        client.Close();
        factory.Close();

    }
```

How to send alerts from IoT Hub back to devices only the messages filtered by stream analytic job?

**Update:**

When I use the above mentioned code for receiving I am getting all the messages from IoT Hub which are sent by raspberry pi.

But when I use the below code for receiving message, I am getting only the messages sent by worker role to IoT Hub.

```
while (true)
        {
            Message receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
            if (receivedMessage == null) continue;

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes()));
            Console.ResetColor();

            await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
        }
```

This is what my requirement is and I am able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

IoT Hub provides bi-directional asymmetrical way of communication between device and the cloud. The process of receiving messages from the cloud on your IoT device is described quite well [in this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d/).

In short, try to use the following code to receive cloud-to-device messages from IoT Hub:

```
while (true)
{
    Message receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
    if (receivedMessage == null) continue;

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes()));
    Console.ResetColor();

    await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
}
```

Here `deviceClient` is the instance of `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient` which you create like this:

```
deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUri, 
  newDeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey("myFirstDevice", deviceKey));
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. The article you are mentioning is fine. I am able to receive the messages from cloud using my code as well, but here I am receiving all the messages which sent by the raspberry pi. I dont want all messages I want only messages where the temperature value greater than 25. For that I am using stream analytics, event hubs and a worker role which will send back the filtered messages to IoT hub.

Comment: @narendramacha, I think the problem with your code might be that you treat IoT Hub as EventHub (which is unidirectional), and thus you are getting the same messages that you send back. With IoT Hub it should not happen like this, that is why I suggest you try some more IoT-specific code like the one in the article.

Comment: What you said is right, After some practicing I observed that the IoT Hub sending messages back only the messages sent by the worker role(in my scenario). When I use DeviceClient Receive method it actually receiving only when the worker role sent message to IoT Hub not the messages sent by the Raspberry Pi @Dmitri Soshnikov